# How to Auto Focus Textfield in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

```
   function ngOnInit() {

    setTimeout(() => this.id.nativeElement.focus(), 5000);

}
```

If you run 2 or 3 times after that they will not focus..

Comment: Do not use ngOnInit, wait for loaded event of your text field and call focus. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: but i want focus when immediately run the program not for wait to load the event..

Comment: You have to wait for the loaded event, that ensures the native view is created and ready to use. So technically you are still focusing as soon it's created / ready.

Comment: Please, can you share the sample because i am not getting that exactly..I add load event but not work..

Comment: Try this - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b3YqNY I have used layoutChanged event which ensures the view layout is completed.

Comment: If i want to use this code in another component, then both was not focus...

Comment: It works every time for me, if you have issues please share a updated sample.

Comment: I want to use this on two different component then they was not work if i used in 1 component they will work fine...